# Google Drive API v3 files.export method throws a 403 error: "Export only supports Docs Editors files."

Tags: python, google-drive-api, mime-types, imagedownload

**Summary**
Trying to download a JPEG file using files.export, but get a Error 403 message: "Export only supports Docs Editors files."

**Description**
I am trying to make use of Google Drive API for a project of mine, which is really all about collecting some pictures, storing them on the Drive, and later loading them back for some processing. Pretty straighforward.
To that extent, I am simply following the [API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export) and the example code snippets provided therein. Now, I was able to upload a picture to the storage. Trying to download it, I ran into this error message:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1D1XpQwrCvOSEy_vlaRQMEGLQJK-AeeZ7/export?mimeType=image%2Fjpeg&alt=media returned "Export only supports Docs Editors files.". Details: "Export only supports Docs Editors files.">
```

The code use to upload the picture looks something like that:

```
 import io
 from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload, MediaIoBaseDownload

# GoogleDrive is a service created with googleapiclient.discovery.build

# upload a picture
file_metadata = {'name': 'example_on_drive.jpg'}
media = MediaFileUpload('example_upload.jpg', mimetype='image/jpeg')
file = GoogleDrive.files().create(
    body=file_metadata,
    media_body=media,
    fields='id').execute()
```

The upload is successful, I get back the file's ID:

```
print(file) 
{'id': '1aBoMvaHauCRyZOerNFfwM8yQ78RkJkDQ'}
```

and I can see it on my Google Drive.
Then I try to access that very same file:

```
request = GoogleDrive.files().export_media(fileId=file.get('id'), mimeType="image/jpeg")
fh = io.BytesIO()
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
done = False
while done is False:
    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
    print("Download %d%%" % int(status.progress() * 100))
```

At which point the error occurs. I see the API Explorer on the website return the same error, which is why I am tempted to conclude that my code is not to blame. This `file.export` only has two inputs and I don't see how exactly I am failing to use it correctly. I looked through similar questions, but most of them deal with downloading text documents and my error message tells me it's got something to do with the doctype. Am I using a wrong `mimeType`?

[Error handling suggestions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors) on the official page do not feature this particular error message.

Have you got any suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the error message of `Export only supports Docs Editors files.`, in order to download the files except for Google Workspace documents (Document, Spreadsheet, Slides and so on), unfortunately, the method of "Files: export" cannot be used. In your case, when you want to download the image file, please use the method of "Files: get". When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
request = GoogleDrive.files().export_media(fileId=file.get('id'), mimeType="image/jpeg")
```

#### To:

```
request = GoogleDrive.files().get_media(fileId=file.get('id'))
```

#### Reference:

- [Download files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads)

  - About the download a file using "export" and "get", you can see it at above official document.

Comment: This doesn't actually download anything for me...And I'm confused, how is this the opposite answer from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71476202/google-drive-authenticate-and-download-files-with-service-account?

Comment: @Ryan Farber About `This doesn't actually download anything for me...And I'm confused, how is this the opposite answer from: stackoverflow.com/questions/71476202/…?`, I would like to support you. But, I cannot understand your situation. So, can you post it as a new question by including more information for correctly replicating `This doesn't actually download anything for me`? By this, I would like to confirm it. When you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion (fresh eyes helped): I've realized it did download actually download the file to a variable in memory...and I've now realized I need to do a subsequent step to save that bytecode to a file on my filesystem.

And the other answer is for handling Google Docs etc :)

Comment: @Ryan Farber Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.