# Get the blob of a drive file using Drive api

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, blob

I used below script to get the blob of `abc.dat` file which is generated via my Apps Script project. With the Drive service, it is easy.
Used oauthScope is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly`

```
function ReadData() {
  var files;

  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Holder");
  if (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();
    var files = folder.getFiles();

    while (files.hasNext()){
      file = files.next();
        if(file.getName()=='abc.dat'){
          var content = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
          return content;
        }    
    }
  }
  return '';
}
```

In order to reduce the authentication scope, Now I am modifying the code to **fully remove** the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` oauthScope and use only the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` oauthScope.

Using the Drive api, I didn't found a direct way to get the blob of a file.
I used this below script to get the blob of a word document file. But it is not working for the .dat file with error `fileNotExportable, Export only supports Docs Editors files, code 403`

```
function getBlob(fileID, format){

  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + fileID + "/export?mimeType="+ format;

  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    method: "get",
    headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  }).getBlob();

  return blob;
}
```

Found this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65053558/google-drive-api-v3-files-export-method-throws-a-403-error-export-only-support) and tried changing the `export` with `get` in the `url`. The returning `blob.getDataAsString()` gives "Not found" now.

The mimeType I used when creating the abc.dat file is `application/octet-stream .dat`. But when check the generated file, its mimeType is `text/plain`. So I used the 'text/plain' as the input for 'format' parameter in `getBlob` function.

.dat file creation code :

```
 var connectionsFile = {
      title: filename,
      mimetype: "application/octet-stream .dat",
      parents: [{'id':folder.getId()}],
    };
      var blobData = Utilities.newBlob(contents);
      file = Drive.Files.insert(connectionsFile,blobData);
  }
```

How can I modify this code to get the blob from the file? or is there any other way around?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that in your situation, it is required to use `get` method instead of `export` method. Because `export` method is used for Google Docs files (Document, Spreadsheet, Slides and so on). When your script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```
function getBlob(fileID) {
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + fileID + "?alt=media";
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    method: "get",
    headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() },
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  }).getBlob();
  return blob;
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Download files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads)

Answer (score 0):

You can watch this video for detail:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mfhx8wPJLe4

```
function getBlob() {
   var fileID= SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getId();
   var blob= DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).getBlob();
   return blob;
}
```